# Why does my libGDX applet produce this SecurityException?

Tags: java, libgdx

I tried [this famous libGDX applet tutorial](http://www.thesecretpie.com/2011/05/being-like-minecraft-or-how-to-run-your.html) to create an applet version of a game; I get a huge stack trace (below). What am I doing wrong?

```
java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for org/lwjgl/util/applet/AppletLoader$2.class
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getCodeSources(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.getCodeSources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.DeployCacheJarAccessImpl.getCodeSources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.openClassPathElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$800(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for org/lwjgl/util/applet/AppletLoader$2.class
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem. The tutorial gets you to sign `lwjgl_util_applet.jar` differently than it was originally signed. If you compared `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of your JAR files with `lwjgl_util_applet.jar`, you'll see it uses SHA-1 while the default is now SHA-256.

To solve this, simply remove the `META-INF` folder from `lwjgl_util_applet.jar` before signing it again. You shouldn't get any more errors after this.

You can also verify your JAR files without uploading them using `jarsigner -verify`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the JAR file containing `org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader` has been tampered with since it was signed. This could be malicious (someone may have replaced the AppletLoader), or maybe someone updated the file by hand and forgot to re-sign the JAR. Or maybe this was a step of the tutorial? I only glanced over it. In any case, Java is being safe by throwing this exception instead of just executing the tampered-with code.

Whichever JAR file contains `org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader`, go get that JAR again from the LWJGL homepage.

Comment: I did get the latest version of LWJGL; I even switched from JOGL to LWJGL, but it didn't affect the signing...

Comment: Did you carefully follow the part of the tutorial that begins with "By default applets are allowed to use a restricted subset of Java. This is not enough for libgdx/lwjgl, so you need to sign ALL jars in the applet dir." ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did, I signed every JAR I could find in my project.

Comment: @ashes999 Would you like this question to be moved to Stack Overflow? You might get more responses there.

Comment: Okay, we can do that. I'll award you the bounty since it's the only answer. Cheers.